# Receiver Operating Characteristics

Tags: r, statistics

Can I expect a continuous ROC curve on binary outcomes(actual,predicted). I am using the following commands on the binary actual and binary predicted outcomes and all I am getting is just a plot with one inflection.The command I am using is

```
library(pROC)
plot.roc(data$actual,data$predicted)
```

The reference sample dataset is

```
Actual                        
0                                
1                                
0                                
1                                
0                                
1 


Predicted
1
0
1
1
0
1
```

Please let me know if there is any alternative explanation and plotting the ROC.

Comment: Is your predicted value actually 1 or 0? If so, how do you imaging thresholds should vary to generate a curve?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to plot the area under the roc curve. Plotting it this way will give you 50% for all points since you do not provide any thresholds.

The whole point of the ROC curve is to provide a more thorough view of your accuracy of the model by plotting the specificities and sensitivities for each threshold (check [here](http://gim.unmc.edu/dxtests/reviewof.htm) ). The threshold (takes values between 0 and 1 since it is a probability threshold) is what determines a test case to be 0 or 1 according to its associated probability. As an example having a threshold of 40%, any predicted case with probability over 0.4 would be classified as 1 (success) and less than 0.4 as 0 (failure). The collection of specificities and sensitivities according to various thresholds is used in the calculation and plotting of the ROC curve.

As an example (from the pROC documentation), in order to use the plot.roc function you could do:

```
#load the data
data(aSAH)

#Create a model so that you get the sensitivities, specificities for different
#thresholds
rocdata <- roc(aSAH$outcome, aSAH$s100b,
               levels=c("Good", "Poor"))

> str(rocdata)
List of 15
 $ percent           : logi FALSE
 $ sensitivities     : num [1:51] 1 0.976 0.976 0.976 0.976 ...
 $ specificities     : num [1:51] 0 0 0.0694 0.1111 0.1389 ...
 $ thresholds        : num [1:51] -Inf 0.035 0.045 0.055 0.065 ...
 $ direction         : chr "<"
 #and so on...
```

And then you can plot it as:

```
plot.roc(rocdata)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested, ROC curves can be plotted when you have a score or probability variable. The ROC cure then plots different false positive rate / true positive rate pairs according to varying thresholds. Your classifier seems to produce 0/1 output, so you can only plot a point in the ROC space. See [Fawcett 2005](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/workshops/mir2009/references/ROCintro.pdf) for more information.

Here is an example of an ROC curve where the predicted value is a probability:

```
library(pROC)

actual <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)
predicted <- c(0.35, 0.55, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6)

plot.roc(actual, predicted)
```

[image]